# How to find Security Group ID in ec2 metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

I'm trying to find security group ID in metadata, but there is only a name of the group.

The get the name with `curl` like this:

```
﻿﻿curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups/
```

RESULT

```
some-secgroup-name
```

I need the ID like this one `sg-1234567911`

Any Idea how to I find in metadata (whitout CLI)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need the MAC address of the instance. To obtain that you can do a `curl` using the metadata url:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac
```

Once you have that, you can get the security groups from the `network` section:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/<your_mac>/security-group-ids
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories